# Date: get the next monday or tuesday from a date

Tags: php, html, laravel, date

I want to compare two dates, the system date against the date of a record, if the system date is a Thursday and the record date is a Monday, print a blinking `<td>`. I used 'next Mon', but it does not work

```
@elseif(date('D') == 'Thu' AND date('D', strtotime($crq->date)) == 'next Mon')
     <td style="background-color: black;color: white"><blink>{{ $crq->date }}<i class="fa fa-exclamation "></i></blink></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date()` will not output "next Mon", it might print "Mon" if the day is in fact on a Monday, but it will not print "next" (this is using the `D` format in `date()`).

You should instead check if the date is the same. You can do that by checking if the dates are exactly the same from the value in your `$crq-date` and `strtotime("next Monday")`, which is the timestamp for the next Monday.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($crq->date)) == date("Y-m-d", strtotime("next Monday"))
```

Here's a [live demo](https://3v4l.org/HlvZo).